# Using resourceQuery with Webpack v3.8.1

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack

I would like to load some `.svg` files directly into the `DOM` into `<svg>` tags. To distinguish between `.svg` files that should be loaded in that manner with the `svg-sprite-loader` and those that should be loaded as files with the `file-loader`, I intend to use the `resourceQuery`.

I have this in my `webpack.config.dev.js`

```
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        oneOf: [
          {
            resourceQuery: /sprite/,
            use: require.resolve('svg-sprite-loader'),
          },
          {
            use: {
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            }
          }
        ],
      }
```

In one of my files, I have the following:

```
import '../../../images/dropdown.svg?sprite';
```

I'm constantly hit by the following error:

```
Unable to resolve path to module '../../../images/dropdown.svg?sprite'  import/no-unresolved
```

I am not sure what is not correct. Please help through.

Comment: if you ignore that error, does the svg gets loaded correctly?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the resource query, but `../../../images/dropdown.svg` is probably too shallow or too deep.

Comment: @PlayMa256, @Tholle, when I comment out `resourceQuery: /sprite/` and remove `?sprite` from the import, it's loading properly but then applying to every `.svg` which is what I would like to avoid with the `resourceQuery`.

Comment: @PlayMa256, I have inspected the `DOM` and actually, regardless of the error, the `svg` is being loaded properly!

Comment: Just ignore this eslint-error then.

Comment: Unfortunately, the application fails to compile because of the error. @PlayMa256

Comment: It fails to compile because it is an eslint error. You can add `// eslint disable-next-line` (just double check on this, i dont remember) above this line to remove the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointers @PlayMa256 Tholle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @PlayMa256 suggests, ignore `eslint-error`:

```
    "import/extensions": 0,
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
```

in `.eslintrc`

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without disabling those rules in eslint?

Eslint seems to dislike the query string.  The code works, but eslint isn't reading the webpack config properly?

Answer (score 0):

In order to selectively ignore `.svg` but keep the unresolved rule otherwise you can change your eslint rule in .eslintrc in the following way:

```
'import/no-unresolved': ['error', {
    'ignore': [ '\.svg' ]
}]
```

By this you are telling eslint to raise an error for the unresolved imports but ignore anything that ends with `.svg`